# Jquery removeClass not work on my wordpress theme

Tags: jquery, wordpress, customization

I have this code:

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

```
//Control map markers state
jQuery('body').on('click', '.jet-map-marker', function addPinActive(){

    var pinIcon = jQuery(".jet-map-marker");
    
    if(!pinIcon.hasClass('activeLocation'))
    {
        jQuery(this).addClass('activeLocation');
    }
    else if(pinIcon.hasClass('activeLocation'))
    {
        jQuery('.jet-map-marker').removeClass('activeLocation');
        jQuery(this).addClass('activeLocation');
    }
});

**//CODE NOT WORKING:**

jQuery('.jet-map-close').on('click', function()
{
    jQuery('.jet-map-marker').removeClass('activeLocation');
});
```

});

I the first part, the removeClass function works fine, but in the second (Market with comment) not. I added jquery to the WordPress theme, for this reason the first part work's fine.

Somebody can help me please?

Comment: I would guess that you need to put the second part in a document.ready handler. The first event handler works without this as it's delegated to the `body`

Answer (score 0):

It may have something to do with the fact that the second click listener is sitting on top of the first (the element is in 'body' which has a click listener on it) - which is causing the click on the remove button to also trigger the click on the body. Try adding `e.stopPropagation()` as per this example.

```js
$('body').on('click', function() {
console.log('body clicked');
})

$('.b0').on('click', function() {
console.log('button 0 clicked');
})

$('.b1').on('click', function(e) {
e.stopPropagation()
console.log('button 1 clicked');
})
```

```css
body{
height:100%;
background:#f0f0f0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<button class='b0'>click first</button>
<button class='b1'>click second</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi Kinglish, thank you for your answer but still not working. I tried in a range of forms and not have solution